# Defining property of a variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I am very new to JS.

I am trying to define properties of a variable, but the trick is that I want JS to define a new variable while defining another.

This does not work:

```
var robber = {
        health: 10,
        halfHealth: this.health/2,
};
```

I expect `robber.halfHealth` to be 5, but answer is `NaN`. I guess it does it because var `robber` is not really defined by the time attempt to calculate `halfHealth` is done?

If I put it an another way it works:

```
var robber = {
        health: 10,
        // halfHealth: this.health/2,
};

var robberHalfHealth = robber.health/2;
```

I do not want to have hundreds of variables, but want all variables related to "robber" to live {in one house}, so to say.

P.S. One of ways might be to add function which would define `halfHealth` and do `robber.init()`, but is there a more straightforward solution?

Comment: Instead of declaring a second variable in your second version, you can say `robber.halfHealth = robber.health / 2;` to add a second property to the `robber` after creating it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a function?

```
var robber = { health: 10, halfHealth: function(){return this.health/2;} }
robber.halfHealth(); // 5
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't have the same result in that the function will always return half of whatever the current value of `health` is. If the idea is to be able to tell whether a changeable `health` has dropped below half of its original value this won't work.

Comment: This is true, though, if checking for this is a requirement - I would use a function for that too, then name health => originalHealth/maxHealth and have another property for storing current health